# How to limit android devices according to CPU performance with unity3D

Tags: android, ios7, unity-game-engine

I have recently published my unity game on App Store. I Targeted iOS 7 to eliminate iPhone 3GS for performance reasons. 
Now i am willing to publish my game for android devices with unity but i am not sure how to restrict my game. which configuration should i use with min API level or device filter?
My game uses about 100 % CPU with iPhone 4 and about 50% with iPad 4 retina.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to target higher-end android devices, first of all, try setting the API level to IceCreamSandwhich or above. Next, try limiting your app(in code) to a specific minimum resolution like WVGA (800x480). Any resolution lower than that will mostly be a very old device which cannot run your game. You can also specify model numbers in unity to be exactly for those devices, but I don't really recommend doing that, because many users root their phones and you could have some issues with it. You can also write some code so that your game checks if the device has multiple cores of CPU, but that cannot be done in the Play Store. So for example if a user has a 800x480 screen with ICS+ running, but has a 800Mhz CPU, you cannot do anything about it, he can install the game from the store. But you can force check the CPU cores in game so the game does not start for single core devices etc.
Overall limit the api to ICS+ and the minimum resolution to 800x480.
Hope I could help.