# Does API level says anything about its ARM processor

Tags: android, api, arm

Developing a new app I need to find out which API levels I can support. One of the specs is that the phone needs ARMv7 to run Unity3D. On Android Virtual Device Manager it looks like API 14 is the first version with ARMv7.
Is this correct?

Comment: AFAIK the hardware architecture is independent from the API level. The only thing that seems related is, Google Play filters your app depending on the native libraries included in the manifest. So if you include libs for x86 and ARMv7, your app will only be shown for devices with ARMv7 and X86... But somebody please correct me if im wrong.

Comment: Perhaps there happens to be a non-causative correlation with **emulator** images, but not in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @rupps already said, the api level is indipendent from the underlying architecture. Since google play filter the apps from the store it will not show your app to uncompatible devices.

Some info:
http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/156283-What-is-the-Minimum-API-level-required-for-build-is-Android-builds-in-unity-3-5-2

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/159543-Android-export-minimum-API-level

[How to limit android devices according to CPU performance with unity3D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19565137/how-to-limit-android-devices-according-to-cpu-performance-with-unity3d)

Answer (score 0):

[From NDK docs](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk.git/+/master/docs/text/CPU-X86.text), note this is about native API level however I'm sure unity has some native libraries getting shipped with what you develop.

> ### Compatibility:
>
> The minimal **native API level provided by official Android x86 platform builds is 9, which corresponds to all the native
>   APIs provided by Android 2.3, i.e. Gingerbread** (note also that no new
>   native APIs were introduced by Honeycomb). You won't have to change
>   anything to your project files if you target an older API level: the
>   NDK build script will automatically select the right set of native
>   platform headers/libraries for you.

So in general API level tells something about architecture however since [ARM-NEON is supported from NDK r3](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk.git/+/master/docs/text/CPU-ARM-NEON.text) you can think that as granted on any Android version above 1.5.